# Modifying Legend Title in qplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to change the title of the legend in a qplot, I have searched on the internet but found absolutely nothing. The title that shows up above the categories included in the legend is `Data$Treatment` and I want to change that text to `"Treatment Categories"`. What should I add to my code?

```
qplot(Data$Measurement,
      residuals,
      colour = Data$Treatment,
      shape = Data$Treatment,
      size=I(3.9),
      xlab="Measurement Values",
      ylab="Residuals",
      main="Residuals Plot")
```

I have also tried saving the above command in a variable named `p`, and then running the following command:

```
p + labs(aesthetic='Treatment Categories')
```

Comment: `+ scale_color_discrete(name = 'Treatment Categories')` maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140606/change-composite-legend-title

Comment: or `+ labs(colour="Treatment Categories")`.

Comment: @eipi10, with a slight modification, I got the result I was looking for. Thanks a lot. `labs(colour="Treatment Categories", shape = "Treatment Categories"`

Comment: pls don't use `qplot()`. i spent ages reducing it's presence in `ggplot2` official docs. it's not recommended at all.